# Searching through url in php

Tags: php, url, seo

I want to make a function in php through which will act as a search engine for my database and will search whatever i the user is giving in the url. is it possible?

**Example** : If my url is like *www.shop.com* and it has a page as *www.shop.com/Sarees*.

Now if a user goes to the link and types *www.shop.com/Designer-sarees* then there must be a search for designer sarees in the database and on page we can display all result of designer sarees. How can i do it. I am not able to give it a start even. please help..

It is something related to SEO any assistance or reference would be appreciated.

Comment: extract search key from url and match it in your db result and display. try to get url segments http://www.timwickstrom.com/server-side-code/php/php-get-uri-segments/

Comment: use [Parse URL](http://uk3.php.net/parse_url) and explode the path on '/' chars?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using php you can some thing like this

```
$url=explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$url_new=explode('?',$url[YOUR_INDEX]);
```

and then you can fire select query in your database with **LIKE** clause and can display all matching result.
Hope this help :)